# In GraphQL, how can I create a case insensitive query that works for looking up a name within a search bar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, searchbar, react-typescript

Query:

```
const query = gql`
    query FindFeeder($search: String) {
        feeder_unit(
            where: {
                _or: [{ serial: { _ilike: $search } }, { name: { _ilike: $search } }, { household: { name: { _ilike: $search } } }]
            }
        ) {
            id
            serial
            name
        }
        user_account(
            where: {
                _or: [
                    { email: { _ilike: $search } }
                    { first_name: { _ilike: $search } }
                    { last_name: { _ilike: $search } }
                    { household: { units: { serial: { _ilike: $search } } } }
                ]
            }
        ) {
            userId: uid
            email
            firstName: first_name
            lastName: last_name
            alternateId: alternate_id
        }
    }
`;
```

I need help trying to make this query work when a user searches someone's name with a space along with it being case insensitive. For example, when the user types in "John Doe" or "john doe", the query should return John Doe's information. Instead, it produces no results.

Comment: use playground ... before coding ... API [implementation] specific problem

Comment: I tried using the playground and it did not work at all.

Comment: then searching for client code solution doesn't make sense ... ask API devs

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a simple way to do this. GraphQL doesn't support case insensitive searches, but regex does. Something like this should work for you.

{ email: { regexp: $search }}

where $search comes through like "/johndoe@email.com/i"